# Separating number input into units

Tags: c++, algorithm, pseudocode

I need to separate users input into units and store them in an array. 
e.g if user enters 6547. Array will store {6,5,4,7} Using C++ on Linux

I would appreciate if you can help me with pseudocode or explain an algorithm.

I'm a beginner so please restrain from advising advanced function (and explain its use if you do) as we have studied basics so far

**N.B|** If such question has already been answered and I skipped it in search, please do point me to it.

Comment: You have to *try something*, not just ask Stack Overflow for the code. First figure out how to convert a decimal character to an integer. (Hint: Subtract `'0'`). Then iterate over each character, converting it, and putting it into an array.

Comment: I did think over it before asking. I know can use static_cast for converting it into an integer.The problem is in 'iterate over each character', how do i do that? Operating on last digit and coming towards left. I tried taking modulus, using %10 to as I need units but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math for isolating right most digit:

```
digit = digit % 10;
```

The math for shifting a number right by one digit:

```
new_number = old_number / 10;
```

Every letter and number can be represented as a text character.  For example, '5' is a character representing the single decimal digit 5.

The math for converting a textual digit (character) to numeric:

```
digit = char_digit - '0';
```

Example:

```
  digit = '9' - '0';
```

The math for converting a numeric digit to a textual digit (character):

```
char_digit = digit + '0';
```

Example:

```
  char_digit = 5 + '0';
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not dividing old number by 10 to get the new number. I use `static_cast` for converting into integers. Can you explain on `digit = char_digit - '0';`

Comment: Done. I up voted it previously but apparently the lost reputation on this question stripped my rights to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem basically breaks into few parts, which you need to figure out:

1. how to read one character from input
2. how to convert one character to the digit it represents
3. how to store it in the array

Please, try to explain if you have problem with some particular point from the list above or there is a problem somewhere else.

Comment: I was having the problem in first step. Which is now cleared thanks to Thomas's reply above.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Variable input_string holds the number entered by the user & you want to store it in an array named 'a'...Here's a C snippet.. you can easily convert it into C++ code.. 
I would recommend taking the input as string rather than int so that you can directly insert the digits extracted from the end...(else you can start storing the integer from beginning and then reverse the array)

```
scanf("%s",&input_string)
size = strlen(input_string)-1
input = atoi(input_string)
while (input/10>0)
{
    i=input%10;
    input=input/10;
    a[size]=i;
    size--;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C++11 solution:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
int num = std::stoi(input);
std::vector<int> v_int;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
{
    v_int.push_back(num % 10);
    num /= 10;
}
// To get the numbers in the original order
std::sort(v_int.rbegin(), v_int.rend());
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v_int.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << v_int[i] << std::endl;
}
```

If you want it in a c-style array, do this:

```
int* dynamic_array = new int[v_int.size()];
std::copy(v_int.begin(), v_int.end(), dynamic_array);
delete dynamic_array;
```